# Stake a claim in / on / to?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

Which preposition should I use with the idiom "stake a claim"? I thought it was "in," but apparently "on" also exists and some online dictionaries have "to" too.

For example:

> Many homesteaders moved west to stake their claim **in/on/to** the Nebraska territory.
>
> Hundreds of thousands of Mexicans immigrate to the U.S. every year, seeking to stake their claim **in/on/to** American soil and lead a better life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stake a claim to" is most common, as shown by [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stake+a+claim+to%2C+stake+a+claim+in%2C+stake+a+claim+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstake%20a%20claim%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstake%20a%20claim%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstake%20a%20claim%20on%3B%2Cc0).  About twice as common as "on", four times as common as "in".

If one goes back to 1920, however, "stake a claim on" was more popular.  This likely related to the fact that it was more literally understood back then -- a process of driving stakes into the ground around a parcel of land.

From the standpoint of syntactic or semantic validity, though, all formations are equally valid.  So a writer is free to choose whichever seems to best express the desired meaning.

In the original examples I'd likely say

> Many homesteaders moved west to stake their claim**s in** the Nebraska territory.
>
> Hundreds of thousands of Mexicans immigrate to the U.S. every year, seeking to stake their claim**s to** American soil and lead a better life.

(Though that second one is a difficult call.)